# What does “Is theirs worth catching?”

Tags: meaning

the complete phrase is the following

> When hiring someone, start with the premise that attitudes are contagious. Then ask yourself one question: Is theirs worth catching?

Is that some common phrase I am not familiar with? I assume they meant to say is their attitudes worth? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, theirs is short for *"their attitude"*.

> Then ask yourself one question: is *their attitude* worth catching?